# Vala: Creating a thread causes properties to get lost

Tags: multithreading, properties, vala

I currently try to learn some vala. After reading the tutorial I wanted to port some apps written in java to vala.

Therefore I tried to write a application which monitors a folder for changes. This monitor should spawn as a seperate thread so the app can do other things will monitoring. Easy job in java.

After doing some research how to monitor (got a hit on stackoverflow btw) I ended up with the following code:

Runner:

```
public class App : Object 
    {
    private const string FOLDER_TO_WATCH = "/home/chr/Work/vala-monitor-test/tmp/";

    public App() {

        GLib.MainLoop loop = new GLib.MainLoop();

        stdout.printf("Folder: %s\n", FOLDER_TO_WATCH);

        try {
            var daemon = new MonitorDaemon( File.new_for_path( FOLDER_TO_WATCH ) );
            unowned Thread<void*> t = Thread.create<void*>( daemon.watch, true );
        }
        catch (ThreadError err) {
            stderr.printf("Error occured: %s", err.message);
        }
        catch (MonitorError err) {
            stderr.printf("Error occured: %s", err.message);
        }

        stdout.printf("waiting..\n");

        loop.run();

    }

    static int main( string[] args ) 
    {           

        if (!Thread.supported ()) {
            stderr.printf ("Cannot run without thread support.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        new App();
        return 0;

    }

}
```

Monitor class:

```
errordomain MonitorError {
    NOT_A_DIRECTORY
}

public class MonitorDaemon : Object {

    // properties
    public File watched_folder { get; construct set; }

    // internal
    private bool _stop = false;


    public MonitorDaemon ( File folder_to_watch ) throws MonitorError {

        if ( folder_to_watch.query_file_type ( FileQueryInfoFlags.NONE ) != FileType.DIRECTORY ) {
            stderr.printf("Unable to watch: Not a directory\n");
            throw new MonitorError.NOT_A_DIRECTORY("Not a directory");
        }

        this.watched_folder = folder_to_watch;

        stdout.printf("Ready to watch %s\n", this.watched_folder.get_path() );

    }

    public void* watch() {

        try {
            FileMonitor monitor = this.watched_folder.monitor_directory ( FileMonitorFlags.NONE );
            monitor.changed.connect( event_happened );
        }
        catch (IOError err) {
            stderr.printf("Error occured: %s", err.message);
        }

        stdout.printf( "Started watching folder: %s\n", this.watched_folder.get_path() );

        while (!this._stop) { }

        stdout.printf( "Stopped watching folder: %s\n", this.watched_folder.get_path() );

        return null;

    }

    public void stop() {
        // cleanup..            
        this._stop = true;
    }           

    private void event_happened ( File file, File? other_file, FileMonitorEvent event_type ) {
        stdout.printf( "File '%s': %s\n", file.get_path(), event_type.to_string() );
    }

}
```

When creating a thread for the method MonitorDaemon.watch the property set in the constructor is null again causing the following output on commandline:

```
Folder: /home/chr/Work/vala-monitor-test/tmp/
Ready to watch /home/chr/Work/vala-monitor-test/tmp/
waiting..

(process:7159): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_file_monitor_directory: assertion `G_IS_FILE (file)' failed

(process:7159): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(process:7159): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(process:7159): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_file_get_path: assertion `G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
Started watching folder: (null)
```

Comment: Solution: Don't initalize the class which contains the fn to be executed as a thread in the same try..catch clause. It causes the above errors. But why???

Comment: Vala is reference counted. When exiting the try{} block it gets unref'd then freed.

Comment: @lethalman: you may want to copy your comment to an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: I wasn't sure I understood the question correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vala is reference counted. When exiting the try{} block it gets unref'd then freed. You must keep the MonitorDaemon alive somewhere.